# Hard drive swapping platters

Tags: hard-drive, firmware, specifications

An old HDD I have went undetected suddenly while working on my PC. The drive didn't spin anymore so I assumed it didn't receive power anymore. I bought - what looks to be - an identical used HDD and swapped the PCBs. The drive started to spin and would intermittently appear in bios but not in the OS.
I decided to swap the platters to see if this would make it work but it didn't. The drive is still not detected (now also not detected in bios).

How can I verify the firmware of the drives and potentially update/change it?

How can I further check that the drive's specs are identical?

Is there anything else worth swapping to make one functional drive from the 2?

I am only interested in potentially recovering some data from the old drive.

Comment: I assume you did all the work in a sterile clean room?

Comment: My old vinyl record wasn't working very well on my record player, so I put it in a bag of gravel & carried it round to my friend's. Oddly, it was even worse there...

Answer (score 2):

> I decided to swap the platters to see if this would make it work but
> it didn't.

You cannot do this (unless you have a proper clean room handy).  Opening the drive housing and changing platters will ruin the drive.

It is also likely that the drive controller may not be compatible with the changed platters.

At this point, if you need to get the data from these platters, take the old drive and platters to a local Recovery Agency and ask them about cost.  Likely high because you have removed the platters.